# Get full objects of one2many records instead of just IDs via XMLRPC in Odoo

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-8

When doing a "read" or "search_read" method call on a model using XMLRPC in Odoo, by default only list of ids of one2many records is returned. Is there a way to get whole objects of relational model class instead of just ids?

Of-course I can get records of related table in a separate XMLRPC call and then match the ids to get full objects. But I was just curious that is there anyway to do it in a single XMLRPC call???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I am aware of in the read/search_read methods.  The alternative would be to do a custom coarse-grained method that assembles the results you want and hands it back.  Same thing with many2many fields AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

XML-RPC cannot marshall openerp browse objects, so we cannot use browse method from xmlrpc. It will give the following error.
"Fault cannot marshal  objects"

So, its best to continue with read method only